# Does Shopify provides Sandbox feature?

Tags: shopify

I'm working on a module which integrates Shopify.
So I want to test my application with real data.
Does Shopify provides Sandbox feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a [partners account](https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/signup) you can set up a test store that will let you create real data to use to test your app. You are limited in the number of orders you can create and can only use the bogus gateway, but everything else is the same.